# Can i drive a 2003 Durango without rear drive shaft remove from transmission in an emergengy?

Tags: dodge, durango, drive-shaft

2003 Durango rear drive shaft had rear universal go out and was pulled out of transmission. It has to be moved could I lock it in 4hi and drive temporarily?

Comment: Does it have a central dif? Have you blocked the hole?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! One of the biggest issues you'll run into is keeping the transfer juice inside the transfer case. If you pulled the slip yoke out of  it, there's nothing there to seal it up. Physically you *should* be able to do as you are suggesting and use the front drive to do what you need, but it is not something I'd recommend or do myself.